# Зависит ли поддерживаемая версия Android от Gradle в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, api, gradle, sdk

Мне нужно, чтобы написанное мною в Android Studio приложение работало под Android 4.4. Для этого я выставляю в Project Structure версию API 20, а версию Build Tools 26.0.2. Также у меня стоит Gradle 4.1 и Plugin version 3.0.0 согласно табличке.

Зависят ли последние версии модулей от версии API? Как понять, какие версии использовать. Потому что есть сомнения, что если использовать только последние версии, то и программа будет работать только на последней версии Android.

Подскажите где можно почитать об этом или скажите, какие версии проставляете Вы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать всегда нужно самые последние версии компонентов IDE и версии библиотек поддержки, так как в них постоянно вносятся улучшения и новые возможности, фиксятся баги. Так, сборка на gradle 4 в несколько раз быстрее, чем на gradle 2.

То, какая минимальная версия API будет поддерживаться вашим приложением определяется только параметром `minSDKversion` в конфиге грэдл - это единственное необходимое условие. Значения `compileSDKversion` и `targetSDKversion` должны соответствовать последним актуальным API, как правило (сейчас API27). Так же данные параметры можно настроить в окне *Project Structure* на вкладке *Properties* указывается версия `compileSDKversion` (она должна быть равна последней актуальной версии API, сейчас это API 27, на вкладке *Flavors* - минимальная (и таргет версия) - именно здесь вам нужно указать значение API 20 в строке `minSDKversion`:

[image: screen]

Все это уже сказано в ответе ранее, а обратить внимание я хотел на такой момент (так как в вопросе есть какие версии использовать). В проекте мажорные версии (первая цифра до точки) утилиты сборки (build tools), версии библиотек поддержки (support library) и значение `compileSDKversion` должны совпадать - сейчас это 27. Так же соответствующее API должно быть установлено в SDK Manager студии (tools -> android -> SDK Manager). Следить за актуальностью версий этих компонентов можно в том же SDK Manager (вкладка *SDK Tools*), который показывает как наличие обновлений, так и проводит само обновление. Для библиотек поддержки студия делает отметку в файле build.gradle - подсвечивает каким то болотным цветом строку с зависимостью, если она имеет более новую версию, нажав на "лампочку" слева можно исправить на актуальные параметры (для этого в SDK Manager должен быть установлен *Android Support Repository* и своевременно обновлятся):

[image: screen]

Версии системы сборки Gradle и плагина gradle так же имеют определенную связь (для gradle 4 версия плагина не менее 3), но за актуальностью этих параметров, если вы не смелый экспериментатор, следить не стоит - достаточно того, что студия сама устанавливает при обновлении своей версии.В связи с этим предложения самой студии о обновлении игнорировать не стоит, с ними появляется поддержка новых возможностей. В редких случаях IDE выводит уведомления о необходимости обновить систему сборки (обычно при запуске этой самой сборки) - здесь приходится подчиниться, так как иначе проект собирать она не будет. Обычно для этого достаточно нажать на ссылку в самом сообщении.

Comment: По поводу версий суппорта не все так однозначно. Поднимать версии надо, но кроме исправлений очень часто завозят если не откровенные баги, но изменение поведения. Короче проверять все надо дополнительно, не отвалилось ли чего.

Comment: @YuraIvanov да, такое имеет место быть. Самое лютое обычно фиксят, пока API в альфе\бете (как сейчас есть саппорт-либы с мажорным номером 28). Я специально сделал акцент на актуальной версии API (как сейчас 27), а не бэтах - к релизу обычно уже можно пользоваться, хотя и не без неожиданностей порой, согласен.

Answer (score 5):

Версия Gradle и AS никак не влияют на minAPI — это просто система сборки и IDE соответственно. Собирать проект можно хоть руками — для этого есть javac и jar (из JDK) и куча утилит из android sdk (тот же dex, емнип это и есть те самые build tools), это жутко неудобно и gradle просто облегчает процесс. Для поддержки свежих андроидов может потребоваться более новая версия gradle плагина, но не наоборот. То же самое относится и к build tools.

Минимальный *требуемый* API задаётся в файлах проекта, как и целевой (от него зависят параметры оптимизации и поведение некоторых системных классов). От минимального зависит доступность определённых классов Android, но она зачастую может быть предоставлена android support library.

Так что можно смело использовать самые новые средства разработки и писать код даже под Froyo (android 2.3).

Comment: Froyo это 2.2 :)